# Python ctypes mutable string in struct

Tags: python, c, struct, ctypes

I have the following C struct that contains a mutable C-style string.

```
typedef struct XMLCFG_PARAMS {
    unsigned long       ulMedia;                    // Save/load to file or buffer
    unsigned long       ulCfgFlags;                 // Flags say what type of info to save/load
    char*               pszBufOrFilename;           // The buffer or the filename 
    unsigned long       ulBufLen;                   // How long is the buffer (in bytes)
} XMLCFG_PARAMS;
```

I've defined the structure in Python like so:

```
class XMLCFG_PARAMS(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("ulMedia", ctypes.c_ulong),
        ("ulCfgFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
        ("pszBufOrFilename", ctypes.c_char_p),
        ("ulBufLen", ctypes.c_ulong),
    ]
```

This structure is then instantiated:

```
xml_cfg = XMLCFG_PARAMS()
xml_cfg.ulMedia = XMLCFG_BUFFER
xml_cfg.ulCfgFlags = config_flags
xml_buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(xml_text, size=1024 * 1024)
xml_cfg.pszBufOrFilename = ctypes.c_char_p(ctypes.addressof(xml_buffer))
xml_cfg.ulBufLen = len(xml_buffer)
```

The C call returns with the error `WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x6E6F697B`.

I suspect that I'm doing something wrong with the way I'm instantiating the`XMLCFG_PARAMS` struct, specifically the `pszBufOrFilename` field as this is the first time I've encountered a mutable C-style string in a struct.

### C Function Signature

```
BOOL Control(unsigned long   ulEngId,
             unsigned long   cmd_id,
             unsigned long   *ulParam0 = 0,
             unsigned long   *ulParam1 = 0,
             unsigned long   *ulParam2 = 0,
             unsigned long   *ulParam3 = 0);
```

### Python ctypes call

```
dll_handle.Control(engine_id, cmd_id, ctypes.pointer(xml_cfg), None, None, None)
```

Output of `hex(ctypes.addressof(xml_buffer))` is `0x3940020` while the exception keeps referring to `0x6E6F697B`. This is on Win XP, so I guess this memory address doesn't change because the OS lacks ASLR.

Comment: One problem with what you're doing is the `xml_cfg` struct doesn't get a reference to the buffer in its `_objects` dict. So `xml_buffer` could become unreferenced and deallocated, which leaves a bad pointer in `pszBufOrFilename`. This can't happen if you instead assign `xml_cfg.pszBufOrFilename = ctypes.cast(xml_buffer, ctypes.c_char_p)`. In this case `xml_cfg._objects` references the buffer to prevent it from being deallocated.

Comment: To help debug this, please show the C function signature and how you're calling it. Also print the value of `hex(ctypes.addressof(xml_buffer))` before calling the function.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks for the comments. I've updated the question with the relevant information. I don't understand why `ctypes.c_char_p(ctypes.addressof(xml_buffer))` won't keep a reference to `xml_buffer` while `ctypes.cast(xml_buffer, ctypes.c_char_p)` will? Is that because `types.addressof` does not increment the object reference count?

Comment: Is the `xml_buffer` read-only or may the C code modify its contents? I'm not a ctypes expert by any means, but it may be also worth trying: `xml_cfg.pszBufOrFilename = xml_buffer.value`. FWIW, your original code works ok for me, but I'm just testing it on Linux with a simple `libc.printf` call in the script itself.

Comment: @PM2Ring `xml_cfg.pszBufOrFilename` is modifiable by the C function.

Comment: @eryksun If I write the line as `xml_cfg.pszBufOrFilename = ctypes.cast(ctypes.create_string_buffer(1024 * 1024), ctypes.c_char_p)` and skip the temporary `xml_buffer` variable, the code works! It must be something to do with xml_buffer being deallocated.

Comment: `ctypes.addressof(xml_buffer)` is just the integer address; it really wouldn't make sense for it to increment the refcount of `xml_buffer`. So you're basically assigning `xml_cfg.pszBufOrFilename = ctypes.c_char_p(some_number)`, which has no reference back to `xml_buffer`. In contrast, the temporary `c_char_p` created via `cast` does reference the source object in its `_objects` dict, which gets carried over in the assignment to `pszBufOrFilename`.

Comment: FYI, in the call it's more efficient to use `ctypes.byref(xml_cfg)`. There's no need to create a ctypes pointer. `byref` passes the object's internal pointer to the C data buffer.

Comment: Hey @eryksun: How about you put this info into an answer so we can upvote it? :)

Comment: @PM2Ring, CadentOrange may have a different problem. If the problem was `xml_buffer` getting deallocated, I would expect an access violation somewhere in the range of 0x3940020 - 0x3A40020. But it's at address 0x6E6F697B. Of course, it could be an indirect AV caused by the function overwriting a newly-allocated pointer in that range. It's difficult to say without a debugger, or at least without more of the calling context to see whether `xml_buffer` is still in scope at the time (if so, it's definitely not deallocated).